# Convex function inequality for Euclidean norm: $\|(f(x_1),\cdots,f(x_n))\|_2\leq f(\|x\|_2)$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a positive, convex, continuous function such that $f(0)=0$. (If you wish you can also suppose $f$ to be monotone increasing.)
I would like to prove or to disprove the following inequality: 
$$\|(f(x_1),\cdots,f(x_n))\|_2\leq f(\|x\|_2),$$
for all $x=(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $x_i\geq 0$ for all $i=1,\cdots,n$; where $\|\cdot\|_2$ is the usual euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: feels similar to Jensen's inequality

Comment: Presumably you wantt $f(x) \ge 0$? Otherwise $f(x) = -x$ will give an immediate violation.

Comment: yes, i forgot. But f(0)=0 in addiction with f increasing will imply positivity

Comment: anyway thank you, i edited the post

Comment: @gt6989b yes, I agree with you, but it's a little bit subtle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $g$ be the linear function that agrees with $f$ at $0$ and $\|x\|_2$: specifically,   $$g(t) = \frac{f(\|x\|_2)}{\|x\|_2} t$$
By convexity, $f(t)\le g(t)$ for $0\le t\le \|x\|_2$. Assuming $f$ is nondecreasing, we also have $|f(t)|=f(t)\le g(t)$. Hence, 
$$\|(f(x_1),\cdots,f(x_n))\|_2\leq \|(g(x_1),\cdots,g(x_n))\|_2 = g(\|x\|_2) 
= f(\|x\|_2)$$

---

Without the assumption that $f$ is nondecreasing the inequality fails: nothing prevents $f$ from becoming very negative between $0$ and $\|x\|_2$, making $|f(x_k)|$ huge.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you.